# Conditional WHERE clause with IN syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to write SQL query with conditional WHERE clause. 
My entire query looks like this:

```
SELECT XXX
FROM table1 TBL 
JOIN table2 TBL2 ON TBL.Id = TBL2.TBL_Id 
WHERE TBL.Id = IIF(@variable IS NULL, Id, @variable )
AND TBL.Id IN( IIF(@tmp = 1, (SELECT Id FROM @tmpTable), Id))
```

Thing what I want to reach is that

> if @tmp is 1 then select all ids from @tmpTable, otherwise select all (equivalent to deletion of whole row)

Condition below is working (without IN part)

```
TBL.Id = IIF(@variable IS NULL, Id, @variable)
```

but the same thing with IN part is not working correctly

```
TBL.Id IN( IIF(@tmp = 1, (SELECT Id FROM @tmpTable), Id))
```

All times it writes an error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Any ideas, what am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Rewrite to use AND/OR instead. (The IN IIF condition...)

Comment: The answer has already been given below, but it can be interesting for you to understand why the error occurs. the IFF is expecting a single value to be returned, where your select is returning an set of values. That's why your first statement works and your second does not.

Comment: @Jens thanks, it makes sense, I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do something like this;

```
SELECT XXX
FROM table1 TBL
JOIN table2 TBL2 
    ON TBL.Id = TBL2.TBL_Id
WHERE (@variable IS NULL AND TBL.Id = Id)
    OR (@tmp = 1 AND TBL.Id IN (SELECT Id FROM @tmpTable))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite your condition with `OR` instead of the `IIF` :

```
SELECT XXX
FROM table1 TBL 
JOIN table2 TBL2 ON TBL.Id = TBL2.TBL_Id 
WHERE (@variable IS NULL AND TBL.Id = Id) 
   OR ((@tmp = 1 AND TBL.Id IN(SELECT Id FROM @tmpTable))
        OR TBL.Id = Id)
```